# query result column name truncates on sql 2014 management studio

Tags: ssms, ssms-2014

```
This Question is not a duplicate of this another question
```

[Resultset column width in Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124514/resultset-column-width-in-management-studio)

```
I am not looking to expand a column based on result value.
I am looking to expand column based on column header text.
Besides, it works on one version and not on another version.
```

I have this below simple query

select 'test column data' testcollengthyname,3434 'testid'

when I run this on sql 2014 management studio

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.5000.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    12.0.5000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                            6.3.14393
```

I get this result

[image]

When I run this on sql 2014 management studio on a different machine

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                            6.3.14393
```

I get the column names truncated with ...

[image]

Is there a setting in this version of management studio that allow me view result with no truncated columnname?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resultset column width in Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124514/resultset-column-width-in-management-studio)

Comment: @GSerg - No it is not a duplicate of that. I am not looking to expand a column based on result value. I am looking to expand column based on column header text. Besides, it works on one version and not on another version.

Comment: My point was that it is a duplicate because it explains that you have no control over column widths when making a query in SSMS.

Comment: no, if we don't have control over column width, how does it works on a different minor version. I am looking for a patch or upgrade option that someone used to fix this.

Comment: Then it's even more certainly a duplicate because it provides a link to a [Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/356926/ssms-grid-alignment-column-width-seems-arbitrary) about this problem and [mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20124676/11683) that it should be fixed in a late build of SQL Server 2016.

Comment: both the versions I mentioned are sql 2014